# c# save content of dynamical created textbox to variable

Tags: c#, matrix, textbox, calculator

this is my first post so far. you should also know, that i'm into c# for just some weeks now because i am doing a course @ university (bochum, germany) to get into it!

heres my question: we have to create a matrix calculator.

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; i < rows ; j++)
{
TextBox boxA = new TextBox();
[...]
boxA.Text = "0"; //to display 0 in every box by launch
Controls.Add(boxA);
}
}
```

this + variable positioning info (to make it look like a matrix) is how i create the boxes.
columns and rows comes from an action that starts on comboboxRows(/Columns)A.selectedIndexChanged(..); and reads the # with comboboxRowsA.SelectedIndex(..);.

if you click on the addition-button then, it should first extract the entrys the user made in the textboxes (afterwards calculate, but i am not at that point now :D) - and there goes my question: how (and where: list<>, array?) to save those numbers.

i hope you get the idea of what i need :-)

thanks, thomas.

Comment: It's unclear what you need. You already know there is a `List<>` class, so what is your question? Do you have problems using it? Do you get errors?

Comment: i am able to save the standard-box.Text i give ("0") every box by launch to a list or array, whatsoever. but i don't know how to get the input the user made!

Comment: Post your code and post your problem. We won't write your Hausarbeit for you.

Comment: sorry. i edited the code in! i don't want anyone to write my code.. just give me the missing command(s) :S

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you don't know how to retrieve your numbers later, because `boxA` is no longer a valid variable. Make a `List<TextBox>` and store all textboxes you create in it, so you can later access all textboxes on your form easily.

Comment: i got it !
        private void readA(int zeilen, int spalten)
        {
            int counter = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < zeilen; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < spalten; i++)
                {
                    arrayA[j, i] = Convert.ToInt32(listeA[counter].Text);
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }

            }
        }
this is how i get it from list to the array. thanks!
edit: ok, code in an comment doesn't look good. i will post it in my question

Comment: Great. On StackOverflow, but also in your own private code, you may want to stay with english for variable and function names. It's easier to read if you don't have to context-switch between languages and programming languages use english by default. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) for a discussion on StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: i see stackoverflow as a great platform, which i will visited and use more often! so i'm going to write the code in english, also to prevent myself from translating my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:

```
    int[,] arrayA = new int[6, 6]; //max dimensions is a 6x6 matrix
    List<TextBox> listeA = new List<TextBox>();
```

*

```
private void readA(int zeilen, int spalten)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < zeilen; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spalten; i++)
            {
                arrayA[j, i] = Convert.ToInt32(listeA[counter].Text);
                counter= counter + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is to add the boxes to a list -> listeA. Then, put it into an array -> arrayA. So you are able to get connection to the entered numbers, e.g. by arrayA[2,3]
thanks again to @nvoigt !! :-)